# c3 graph - show timeseries x axis in AM/PM local time

Tags: javascript, typescript, c3.js

I am using the [C3 chart library](http://c3js.org) and have timeseries data where the values for the X axis are in UTC ISO 8601 format, for example `2017-01-27T11:24:36.012Z` (the same format you get using new Date().toISOString()). I wish to display the ticks in local time.

I set the chart up as follows...

```
var now = new Date().toISOString();

  this.lineChart = generate({
    bindto: '#line',
    transition: {
      duration: 1000
    },        
    data: {
      x: 'x',
      xFormat: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ',
       columns: [
      ['x', now], 
      ['data1', 0]                   
    ]
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        localtime: true,
        tick: {
          format: '%H:%M %p',
          culling : true,
          rotate : 60
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

and then load in extra data, where I have a start time and end time, and I want to show a point every 15 minutes..

```
  let startTime = new Date(startDateTime);
  let endTime = new Date(endDateTime);
  let nextDate = startTime;
  let dates = new Array<string>();
  dates.push(nextDate.toISOString());
  let data = [];
  while (nextDate <= endTime) {
    nextDate = moment(nextDate).add(30, 'm').toDate();
    dates.push(nextDate.toISOString());
    data.push(0); // to make them show up!
  }

  this.lineChart.load({
    columns: [
      ['x', ...dates],
      ['myData', ...data]          
    ]
  })
```

This produces the following...

[image]

Two things are wrong here.

1. The data is the UTC time, ie the first value 22:00 is UTC; local time should be +8:00 hours (for my region)
2. If the 22:00 was correct, I would have thought this should show as 10:00 PM, not the 24 hour format.

As far as I can see the format strings look correct.

Does anyone know what could be wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A **workaround** for this is to forget about `xFormat` and convert all the strings to a "date number", I used `Number(new Date(x))` on each of the values and then it all displayed ok.

Comment: have you considered using a framework like `moment.js`? i am using this in combination with c3 and it's a perfect addition

Comment: @Akoya Yes I do use `moment.js` elsewhere, I just wasn't sure how C3 wanted the date (string) formatted to display it correctly. Just by trial and error I got my solution to work using the number so I don't need to worry about what the string for `xFormat` was mean to be.

Comment: The different formatting options you have for `xFormat` can be found [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md)

Comment: Ah, it's under the **D**3 doco. Thanks for that.

Comment: Second is because of the `%H`. Try with: `%I:%M %p`